# Reset a interface back to Default

Tags: rust

I want to reset all the props as part of the struct back to the default values without missing anything. As i have derived Default i have access to StoreX.default() however not sure of the best way to re-assign each prop on self. Thanks!

```
#[derive(Default, Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Deserialize, Serialize, Store)]
pub struct StoreX {
  pub state: StateX,
  pub name: String,
  pub a: i32
}


impl StoreX {
  pub fn reset(&mut self) {
    let new = StoreX::default();
    self.a = new.a;
    self.name = new.name;
    self.state = new.state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about:

```
*self = StoreX::default();
```